# How do I install Ubuntu on a IMac G5

Tags: mac

I have an old iMac g5 and it can't be upgraded anymore for OS X so I wanted to put Ubuntu on it. I just can't figure it out. I had watched a video that told me to look for Boot Camp Assistance but it isn't on OS X 1.4.

Anything would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at [this FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ) on PowerPC, which will point you to [this Download page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads). There is an answer voted up in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/229794/37165) but OP didn't check it to this date.